# safari fails to upload file when windows authentication is applied?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, safari, windows-authentication

If my site applies windows authentication, my back end can not receive file when using Safari. IE, Firefox and Google Chrome work well? Anyone has idea on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly related to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118150/safari-7-cant-connect-to-intranet-using-http-authentication ?